# Can kinetic and potential energy be converted to thermal energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

If they can, can I use the potential energy equation to find out how much the temperature would increase if 1 kg of water is dropped to the ground from 10m height?

Comment: Lack of attempt can be seen